# Find all grouped records where a records are newer than a certain type of record

Tags: sql, sql-server

That would be the intermediary output I need:

```
Id1, Id2, Type,   Date
1,   2,    test,  2010-10-10
1,   3,    stage, 2010-05-05
1,   2,    stage, 2010-12-12
1,   3,    test,  2010-04-04
1,   3,    prod,  2010-12-31
```

From that point I want to know how many grouped (Id1,Id2) records do exist **after** the record with Type = 'test'.

for the above I would get this final output:

```
Id1, Id2, Count
1,   2,   1
1,   3,   2
```

What sql query would that be?

The use case would be to find all those records who never made it to a later stage than type = "test"

Comment: I don't understand. When you say test, you're refering to date 2010-10-10 or  2010-04-04 ? Looking at your sample output, do you want count for everything except test ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to get the value of Date for "test" Type for corresponding ID1 and ID2 and then make a count of records. Like this:

```
drop table if exists dbo.LaterThan;

create table dbo.LaterThan (
    Id1 int
    , Id2 int
    , Type varchar(100)
    , Date date
);

insert into dbo.LaterThan (Id1, Id2, Type, Date)
values (1, 2, 'test', '20101010')
    , (1, 3, 'stage', '20100505')
    , (1, 2, 'stage', '20101212')
    , (1, 3, 'test', '20100404')
    , (1, 3, 'prod', '20101231')

select
    lt.Id1
    , lt.Id2
    , count(case when lt.Date >= test.Date and lt.Type <> 'test' then 1 else null end) as Cnt
from dbo.LaterThan lt
    outer apply (
            select
                top (1)
                tlt.Date
            from dbo.LaterThan tlt
            where lt.ID1 = tlt.Id1
                and lt.ID2 = tlt.Id2
                and tlt.Type = 'test'
    ) test
group by lt.Id1, lt.Id2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT x.Id1, x.Id2, x.[Date],
       CountAfter = (
           SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.Table1 AS y 
           WHERE x.Id1=y.Id1 AND x.Id2=y.Id2 
           AND y.[Date]>x.[Date]) -- After
FROM dbo.Table1 AS x
WHERE x.[Type]='test'
```

Note: I've assumed that every `{Id1, Id2}` pair of values have only one row with `Type='test'`.

**Edit 1:** If you want to filter all rows with `CountAfter = 0` then

```
SELECT x.Id1, x.Id2, x.[Date]
FROM dbo.Table1 AS x
WHERE x.[Type]='test'
AND NOT EXISTS (
     SELECT * FROM dbo.Table1 AS y 
     WHERE x.Id1=y.Id1 AND x.Id2=y.Id2 
     AND y.[Date]>x.[Date])
```

or (but it isn't an optimal solution)

```
SELECT ...
FROM (
... insert main query ...
) AS mq
WHERE mq.CountAfter = 0
```

Comment: Any idea how I can still filter down to those entries with a count of ZERO ?

Answer (score 0):

I think the query will be,

```
SELECT Id1, Id2, count(Id1) from <table_name> where Type = 'test' group by Id1, Id2;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:

```
SELECT
    t.Id1,
    t.Id2,
    COUNT(*) AS Count
FROM (SELECT Id1, Id2, Date FROM Table WHERE TYPE = 'test') t
LEFT JOIN Table tt
    ON tt.Id1 = t.Id1 AND tt.Id2 = t.Id2 AND t.Date <= tt.Date
    AND tt.Type <> 'Test'
GROUP BY t.Id1, t.Id2
```

Example:

```
DECLARE @table TABLE (Id1 int, Id2 int, [Type] varchar(10),[Date] date)
INSERT INTO @table VALUES (1,   2,    'test',  '2010-10-10'),
(1,   3,    'stage', '2010-05-05'),
(1,   2,    'stage', '2010-12-12'),
(1,   3,    'test',  '2010-04-04'),
(1,   3,    'prod',  '2010-12-31')

SELECT
    t.Id1,
    t.Id2,
    COUNT(*) AS Count
FROM (SELECT Id1, Id2, Date FROM @Table WHERE TYPE = 'test') t
LEFT JOIN @Table tt
    ON tt.Id1 = t.Id1 AND tt.Id2 = t.Id2 AND t.Date <= tt.Date
    AND tt.Type <> 'Test'
GROUP BY t.Id1, t.Id2
```

Answer (score 0):

There might be various dates for similar (Id1, Id2) records. 
So If all you need is a count of the records with this (Id1, Id2) pair irrespective of Date field then this will work for you.

```
SELECT T.Id1,T.Id2,COUNT(*) AS Count 
FROM
   (SELECT Id1, Id2, Date 
    FROM TABLENAME 
    WHERE TYPE = 'test') AS T
GROUP BY
T.Id1, T.Id2
```

Otherwise, you need to add the Date field in `GROUP BY` clause.